# meaning of B={x:{a,b}*|na(x)=nb(x)} in automata?

Tags: automata

meaning of

```
B={x:{a,b}*|na(x)=nb(x)}
```

in automata 
while creating a production for context free grammar?

Comment: This homework question is covered in the lecture notes perhaps

Answer (score 0):

It means B is a m/c which can accept the input in which number of `a` terminals is equal to number of `b` terminals. For example. `aaabbb`, `ababba`, etc..
 Grammar would be like this:

```
S --> aSbS | bSaS
S --> ε
```